# ionic checking network connection before any action

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i have an ionic app with totally 20 page , on each page there is a request to server , most of them are post request ,

is there any way in iconic cordova app , to check network connection and alerting user that that there is no network connection if there is no network connection ?

i can check this in every controller , but i am looking for global handling of this checking  .

below is sample action in controller

```
$scope.sendMessageToManager = function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({ template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>' })
        $http.post(serverConfig.serverUrl + '/api/services/app/hrService/SendMessageToManager', $scope.message).success(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.showAlert();
            $scope.message = {};
        })
    }
```

how can i check network connection before calling sendMessageToManager() ?

is there any specific pattern or guideline for this in cordova ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use cordova-plugin-network-information, to check network connection in ionic.

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

When running on device, you can check.

> $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();

Joshmorony wrote tutorial about it. [HERE](http://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event into your app.js

like

`document.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
        //$state.go('offline', {}, {reload: true});
        alert('No Internet');
}, false);`

Comment: does this happen when user click button and call to any post function happen ? or when app goes offline ?

Comment: when user goes to offline then it automatic call offline event no need to check manually

Comment: i am using  $ionicLoading.show() when user click a button , i cant call  $ionicLoading.hide() in app.js when app goes offline

Comment: ok i have an idea

when app offline also add  $ionicLoading.hide() into offline event and i am sure if $ionicLoading.show not there then it will not give any error

Answer (score 0):

Following up the answer from Aung Myat Hein, you need to get the cordova-plugin-network-information.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

In which if you need a simple way, u can set it into your localstorage.

For offline handling:

```
    document.addEventListener("offline", function()
    {
        console.log("in offline event listener");
        self.events.publish('internetStatus', 'off');
        this.local.set("internet", "off"); //sets the localstorage
    }, false);
```

for online handling it would be:

```
    document.addEventListener("online", function()
    {
        console.log("in online event listener");
        self.events.publish('internetStatus', 'on');
        this.local.set("internet", "on"); //sets the localstorage
    }, false);
```

No matter where you are at, before calling your HTTP requests, you can do a check by getting the value of the key( in this case, internet) from the local storage.